# Как определить присутствие в устройстве акселерометра (гироскопа)?

Tags: javascript

Имеется JS скрипт. В зависимости от присутствия или отсутствия гироскопа в устройстве должны выполняться 2 разных условия. **Вопрос**: как проверить его наличие?

Сейчас у меня в коде прописано просто `let gyroPresent = true;`. Но нужно, чтобы в эту переменную записывался результат выполнения функции, определяющей, присутствует ли гироскоп или нет.

Разумеется, искал решение самостоятельно. Но ни одно не подошло, потому что: либо наличие гироскопа не определяется (хотя он в телефоне присутствует), либо не определяется его отсутствие. То есть с телефона выполняется условие при `true` и с ПК тоже (хотя гироскопа в ПК нет, разумеется).

Проверял примерно так:

```
let gyroPresent = false;
window.addEventListener("devicemotion", function() {
    // ...
    gyroPresent = true;
    // ...
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33833492/how-do-i-detect-if-a-device-has-a-gyroscope-in-a-web-browser такой хак на англоязычном ресурсе есть

Comment: @iksuy Да, я именно про него и говорил. А еще чуть выше в вопросе я уточнил, что он *не работает* у меня.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте такой подход:

```
if (window.DeviceOrientationEvent) {
  // gyro exist
}
```

[Источник](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/device-orientation/)